# Show entire number value after chosen on UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a little coding problem at the moment. I have a picker with 7 different options, currently for testing purposes I have a label that will display the chosen value of the picker.

The problem that I am having is that my label is only displaying whole numbers, not displaying the entire decimal number, can someone please help me so that I can obtain the full value of the chosen item in the picker?

Here is my code :

```
// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [tempList count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    return [tempList objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
      didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
       inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

   CGFloat chosenValue;

    switch (row) {
        case 0:
            chosenValue = 0.0000373;
            break;
        case 1:
            chosenValue = 0.0000273;
            break;
        case 2:
            chosenValue = 0.0000233;
            break;
        case 3:
            chosenValue = 0.0000204;
            break;
        case 4:
            chosenValue = 0.0000179;
            break;
        case 5:
            chosenValue = 0.0000169;
            break;
        case 6:
            chosenValue = 0.0000142;
            break;
        default:
            chosenValue = 0;
            break;
    }

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;

self.testLabel.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(chosenValue)];


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the precision:

```
self.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.7f", chosenValue];
```

The `%f` format specifier defaults to 5 decimal places.

And you probably need to change `chosenValue` to `double` to get enough significant digits.

Better yet, since you are using an `NSNumberFormatter`, set the number of decimals:

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why did you not use NSString stringWithFormat method?

```
self.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.10f", chosenValue];
```

Comment: Well I tried this before @SimoneLai but the problem is that it only partially works (I still need one more position to the right, for example in case 0, I am getting  0.000037 instead of the entire 0.0000373;

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
self.testLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.10f",chosenValue];
```

instead of:

```
self.testLabel.text = [formatter stringFromNumber:@(chosenValue)];
```

Comment: this partially works (I still need one more position to the right, for example in case 0, I am getting  0.000037 )

Comment: @vzm is chosenValue a float? You could change it to a double.

Comment: The problem with using `stringWithFormat` over a number formatter is that the decimal won't be formatted properly based on the user's locale.